# Error in gitlab runner helper with docker executor

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper:x86_64-bd40e3da" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner-helper/manifests/x86_64-bd40e3da": unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://gitlab.com/help/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication#troubleshooting (manager.go:237:4s)

I have provided access token as well in password.

This is my before_script:

```
before_script:
    - echo "password" | docker login --username username --password-stdin
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```